# Will background requests count as visits for Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges?

Tags: support, badges, publicity-badges

Does a request interrupted by cors error count as a visit?

```js
// this one throws a cors error
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/q/2421911/5089567').then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

Does an automatic request made by facebook / gmail bots count as a visit?

```html
<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/q/2421911/5089567">
```

Comment: probably not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what is making the request, but in most cases, no.

We do not actually increment view count by the simple act of loading the page. Instead, upon the page loading, your browser needs to be able to send a request to another /ivc path, which is what actually processes the view and increments the view count (as well as any potential referral count).

If the client that loads the page does not process JavaScript and does not additionally load the backup image to hit that path, then it will not trigger a view for the question. Most bots that just load a page for context when linking, etc will fall into this category - only grab the page source and not further process it. This also occurs if you try to link a page as an image or fetch it via JavaScript - you'll only receive the source code back and a request to the view incrementor will not be made.

We also explicitly have a `Disallow: /*/ivc/*` rule in our [robots.txt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/robots.txt) file, so any bot that respects those rules will not follow that path to increment the view count regardless of its processing technique. We additionally try to detect search engines and throw a 404 page to them, but this won't catch all bots.